writing a kamailio (native language) module for kemi
I noticed that some Kamailio modules are not available in Kemi. I want to learn how to write a Kamailio native module that is unavailable in Kemi (such as Secfilter) for Kemi by modifying the source code.
I observed that some available modules have an API file in src/modules/MODULENAME. However, I found that the Xlog module, which is available in Kemi, doesn't have this file.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"native language" of kamailio is C/gcc https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio/tree/master/src/core. Are you asking how to learn C/C++ in 21 days?

I answered it.
if you look at the modules available in kemi, you can see that they have something named module_registrar. That is the important part. I did it for secfilter and this is an easy process
